# Android ViewOverlay animate during remove() of Drawable

Tags: android, android-animation, android-drawable

I have a ViewOverlay that I use to show a Drawable on the screen. When I want to add or remove the overlay drawable on top of my view I do something like this:

```
ViewOverlay overlay = mView.getOverlay();
overlay.add(mDrawable);
```

...sometime later...

```
ViewOverlay overlay = mView.getOverlay();
overlay.remove(mDrawable);
```

However, this instantly removes my drawable from the screen. Is there a way to fade away the drawable in the overlay instead of just instantly removing it?

Comment: Animate the drawable itself. Once the animation has run its course, call `overlay.remove(drawable)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to apply the animation directly to the `Drawable` first and as soon as the animation is done you can call `remove()` to remove the overlay.

```
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(255, 0);
animator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
animator.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        int alpha = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        mDrawable.setAlpha(alpha);
        mViewThatHasOverlay.invalidate();
    }
});
animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        ViewOverlay overlay = mViewThatHasOverlay.getOverlay();
        overlay.remove(mDrawable);
    }
});
animator.start();
```

Comment: You can make your code shorter by using the `AnimatorListenerAdapter` instead of `Animator.AnimatorListener`. You can selectively override callbacks in the `AnimatorListenerAdapter` and therefore don't have to declare all the callbacks you don't need.

Comment: Additionally you don't have to put the `remove()` call in both `onAnimationCancel()` and `onAnimationEnd()`. `onAnimationEnd()` will always be called when the animation ends. If the animation is canceled it will just first call `onAnimationCancel()` and then directly after that `onAnimationEnd()` so with your original implementation you'd call `remove()` twice when that happens...